# Internal Server Error when uploading files

Tags: php, file-upload, iis-7, upload, internal-server-error

I've made a website on which users can upload a video file. All is fine and it worked like a charm for quite a while. But now all of a sudden (don't think i have changed anything) it will give a `500 Internal Server Error`. As far as i know nothing changed.

All settings in the php.ini file are set to 1gb size and 3000 seconds time for all associated settings. Does anyone know what could cause this?

**EDIT**

I found an error with Id '1' with source name 'named' and the description says cant find the description of the event or error (it's in dutch tho). I did find this:

```
managed-keys-zone ./IN: loading from master file managed-keys.bind failed: file not found
```

Regards,
Dragon

Comment: Verify your permissions and enable errors to display.

Comment: Check the server's error logs. It'll have more details.

Comment: there are no error logs in the logs section of the past 1 hour that have anything to do with it as far as i can see.

Comment: I found some stuff in the logs.. Could you check that?:)

Comment: I just checked the php logs, NOTHING about this error. Nothing from the entire domain. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the size of the file. the only way i could find to work around this is to implement an Javascript upload script. I chose to use [plupload](http://plupload.com/) and now it works as expected.